# Many "cannot be resolved to a type" errors when opening CoGroo project

Tags: java, eclipse

i'm trying to import a CoGroo project, but i cannot do that. Then i try to import i press File>New>Java Project> un-check User Default Location (Eclipse Luna) > Search the folder "cogroo-4.0.0-src" and all the project are inside of that> then when i open my project a lot of "x" stay in the folders and in the projects! what should i do? someone help please!!!
image of when i try to Run it!
i have already tried to import and run this sometimes
[enter image description here][1]

then i try to "import" and i recieve that image!

```
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1HZc.png
```

Comment: It looks like there are libraries missing from the build path.

Comment: What do you mean with "cannot do that"? How does the project you're trying to import tell you to import?

Comment: how can i fix that? =O

Comment: the project isn't telling nothing how to import that .. =((

Answer (score 0):

That is a multi module project. You should add all subprojects to eclipse using "Import...".

Comment: aww i've tried to do that.. and i post a image of that it bugged again